# SQL Storing Age Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization, database-design

Im building an friendship site and I want to store restrictions for when a profile can be viewed.

Right now im using entity-attribute model to store restrictions. Examples of restrictions are what days a profile is available. The issue im having is i want to add a restriction on if a user can view a profile based on a users age range.

Im not sure if this approach is correct for storing, it feels really redundant but maybe im just being picky.

The two restrictions i want to add are minimum age and maximum age. Does this design seem like the correct approach?

**User Attribute Entity Table**

```
id(PK) | userid | attribute | entity
0      | 0      | 0         | 1
1      | 0      | 1         | 188
```

**Attribute Table**

```
id(PK)  | attribute
0       | Minimum Age
1       | Maximum Age
2       | Contact Restricted Days
```

**Entity Table**

```
id(PK)  | attribute_ID | Entity
0       | 0            | 18
1       | 0            | 19
..      | ..           | ..
88      | 0            | 99
89      | 1            | 18
90      | 1            | 19
..      | ..           | ..
188     | 1            | 99
199     | 2            | Monday
..      | ..           | ..
205     | 2            | Sunday
```

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, I now see the userid field.

Comment: So, does entity column in the entity table store user's age value then?

Comment: No it just stores the minimum and maximum age that a user will allow another user to view there profile.

Comment: You could, but why not just throw 3 extra fields onto the user table... MininumAge (int -default 0), MaximumAge (int - default 200), ContactDays (int/enum/flags - default 127) - bit encoded?  It'll make queries a heck of a lot easier and faster.  You can create another table "ContactDays" and fill it with all the combinations if that will make you feel better and place a FK to it.

Comment: Thats what i had originally but then i had 8 more restrictions and i felt adding 11 columns to the user table would be bad db design. Maybe your right thou. The other entities attributes are just true and false.

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit confusing since you have both id and attribute_id in your attribute table. I would think that id (this is your pk or unique column I assume). Similarly, attribute_id column is probably your foreign key referring back to your entity table, I assume?

Comment: thats correct sorry i should have labeled the fk

Comment: Your approach is more customizable, and can be easily expanded to include more attributes, but you'll pay for it in query complexity which will affect your performance.  All depends on how scaleable you need the solution to be.

Comment: Thats true , I guess there no even balance. Either expandibility and customization or performance. Its a choice that needs to be made in every db design.

Comment: No worries! Would you mind if I provide you some suggestions on your table design? I think you have got it down pretty well, but just to save you some headaches down the road. I have some tweaks you could make, if I may?

Comment: Sure go for it, also i just remembered one of the reason why i didnt want to add it to the user table was because it was optional to add these restrictions, so i figured the column would get filled with alot of null values.

Comment: Absolutely! It's best to normalize your data unless you are building a data warehouse. Please see my suggestion and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I think that you've got the `Attribute` and `Entity` columns reversed in your first table ("User Attribute Entity" table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this suggestion as an answer. But here is how I would have designed your table. Having `id` column in each table can cause headaches down the road, especially since you would need to explicitly define the column. Please compare the design below with your tables above:

**User Attribute Entity Table**

```
user_attr_entity_id(PK) | userid | attribute_id| entity_id
                  0     | 0      | 0           | 1
                  1     | 0      | 1           | 188
```

**Attribute Table**

```
attribute_id(PK)  | attribute
0                 | Minimum Age
1                 | Maximum Age
2                 | Contact Restricted Days
```

**Entity Table**

```
Entity_id(PK)  | attribute_id | Entity_Value
0              | 0            | 18
1              | 0            | 19
..             | ..           | ..
88             | 0            | 99
89             | 1            | 18
90             | 1            | 19
..             | ..           | ..
188            | 1            | 99
199            | 2            | Monday
..             | ..           | ..
205            | 2            | Sunday
```

**UPDATE:**

Seems like I must have misread your question initially. I think this design will work just fine. I tested using the query below:

```
SELECT userid
    ,a.attribute_id
    ,e.entity_id
    ,attribute
    ,entity_value
FROM user_attribute_entity_table uae
JOIN attribute_table a ON uae.attribute_id = a.attribute_id
JOIN entity_table e ON e.[entity_id] = uae.[entity_id]
```

Comment: Thanks Rookie13 I see what your saying about the names, it would definitely get confusing the way i had it with the joins.

Comment: You bet! Like I said, you have got this down pretty well. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're building for *speed*, i.e. if you need to optimize it for storing large amount of data, and if you know the "restrictions" (entitys) will not change a lot, then I'd say design it flatter/horizontally:

```
Id | UserId | Restriction1 | Restriction2 | Restriction3 | ..
```

This will however cost you flexibility, make it tougher on future growth/change and limit options.

Your original design is very flexible, and can be compared to a site with language dimensions - X amount of languages on Y amount of elements. Each element/entity should have it's own translation, and they should be easy to add/change.

However, design is somewhat about personal preference also. This is how I would solve it in a similar manner:

```
Users
-------------
UserId | Name


Attributes
-----------------------
AttributeId | Attribute


Entities
-----------------
EntityId | Entity/(or Value)


UserAttributeEntities
------------------------------------
Id | UserId (FK) | AttributeId (FK) | EntityId (FK)/or EntityValue
```

Entity, in my example, can either be it's own table (if values are resued often), or you can just put a column *EntityValue* direclty in the *UserAttributeEntities* table, and skip the *Entities* table.